How does 別にいいですよ mean "It doesn't matter" or "I don't mind"?
A bit confused about how the grammar here is working.
I came across this sentence "別にいいですよ、恋愛漫画読んでたって。"
Which I believe means something like "I don't care/mind, about you having read romance manga."
This looks to be the (not) particularly function of 別に, but it isn't paired with a negative sentence?

In this usage, 別に has the sense of "nothing special".
いいですよ could be rendered as "it's OK".
So the whole sentence could be parsed as, "nothing special, it's OK" which is how the sentence has a sense of "I don't care".
We're taught that いい means "good" but the meaning is a bit broader and is often similar how we use "OK" in English.

This usage of いい is similar to なんでもいい，meaning "anything would be good". It is sometimes translated into English as "I don't care", because you have not expressed a preference.
別 indicates a distinction, between having read romance manga or not having read it.  The speaker is indicating that either side of the distinction is okay with them.

別にmeans"separately" which can be negative or not; it depends on your expectation. Simply: "I don't care if"
